# Correlation matrix between two dataframes per month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

I have two dataframes that have a common index: "Date".

```
data1 = [['0', 100], ['1', 235], ['2', 164]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Date', 'Sales Product 1'])

data2 = [['0', 300], ['1', 105], ['2', 200]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Date', 'Sales Product 2'])
```

each dataframe looks something like this:

| Date | Sales Product 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 |
| 1 | 235 |

What I want is to make a correlation matrix between the sales of product 1 and the sales of product 2 for each of the date values. Something that looks like this

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | Sales product 2 |  |
|  |  | 0 | 1 | 2 |
|  | 0 | corr_value | corr_value | corr_value |
| Sales product 1 | 1 | corr_value | corr_value | corr_value |
|  | 2 | corr_value | corr_value | corr_value |

Try the following:

```
df_corr = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Date')

result = df_corr.groupby('Date').corr()
```

But I get the following:
[image]

Can you help me get the result I want?

Comment: Hi, it might be that you don't have enough values per date in both df1 and df1, try adding more in each.